# One ip address hosts mutiple websites in local network

Tags: apache, teamcity, subdomain, gitlab, subdirectory

So I have a apache server with IP `192.168.1.100` in LAN, now I want to run for example, gitlab and teamcity on it, and don't want to access by port. How do I achieve that, some possible solution I thought out:

- Use sub-directory `192.168.1.100/gitlab`, however click on links like "/path" will go to *192.168.1.100/path*, not *192.168.1.100/gitlab/path*, use *mod_proxy_html* might go too far way I thought
- Use sub-domain? *gitlab@192.168.1.100* or something else? How to?
- Anything else?

Answer (score 0):

Use DNS aliases and redirects. For example, the `teamcity` alias will redirect to `192.168.1.100:8080` where your TeamCity Tomcat is listening, and the `gitlab` alias will redirect to `192.168.1.100:8081` which is picked up by the gitlab server.